# Kubernetes: volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class or spec.StorageClassName

Tags: kubernetes

We're requesting persistence on kubernetes using persistence volume claim.

Currently, we're setting `storage class` using `volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class` annotation:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: vault-file-backend-volumeclaim
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: heketi
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

However, we've realized that exists an `spec.storageClassName` field, we don't know what's it for...

Could we remove `volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class` annotation by setting `spec.storageClassName`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should opt for `storageClassName`, because the annotation will be deprecated in the future, as state in [kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class):

> In the past, the annotation `volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class`
>   was used instead of the storageClassName attribute. This annotation is
>   still working, however it will become fully deprecated in a future
>   Kubernetes release.

So your YML file will be the following:

`storageclass.yml`:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1  
kind: StorageClass  
metadata:  
  name: heketi
provisioner: kubernetes.io/glusterfs  
parameters:  
  resturl: [...]
  restuser: [...]
  restuserkey: [...]
```

`pv.yml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: vault-file-backend-volumeclaim
spec:
  storageClassName: heketi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```